# How does UiAutomator and HierarchyViewer tools of android studio able to get the view hierarchy? Which class pushes data to them

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, layout

I want to understand how UiAutomator and HierarchyViewer works. How can they able to get the view hierarchy of all the applications in current window.

As far as I know, all apps run in separate process and different processes don't share data. So which class is pushing the view hierarchy to these tools?

Thanks

Comment: The hierarchy Viewer tools has already android API inside it to showcase all the view class of your project

Comment: didn't get you? Why should hierarchy Viewer tools have an api for this.. they only receive data

Comment: Have a look how they interact: http://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html#uia-viewer

Comment: Just want to understand a simple thing...as uiautomator can get the view hierarchy of views.. is there any way I can get the view also...like uiautomator shows me that view is TextView and some other properties like clickable, text on it, etc.. but can I get TextView reference i I have id of it?

Comment: @zIronManBox I just want View object.. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Are you doing ui testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101082/discussion-between-user3265443-and-zironmanbox).

Comment: Yes.. i am doing UI testing.. but want the view object that uiautomator shows on screen

Comment: You can get any view using the ID you would have provided.

Comment: that was just for my app? I can see view hierarchy of all the apps that are currently displaying using UIAutomator. I want the view objects of other apps also

Comment: You can't access other apps, you would be basically tampering their copyrights.

Comment: Why would you need UI views of other apps?

Comment: I don't want to access other apps... I just want to know the view objects that are currently displaying on the window. Yes they are from other apps but how am I tampering their copyrights. I just want the the view objects clone..not tempering the view objects that are currently showing...

Comment: If you really get to know what views other apps are using, then you could technically incorporate it, there by making it illegal. But if you want to understand what views are being used by other popular apps, then that's a different SO question.